# C++20 [[no_unique_address]]'s bug in GCC?

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++20, allocator

C++20 introduces the new attribute: [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) which indicates that the data member need not have an address distinct from all other non-static data members of its class.

So I try to use this new attribute to implement my own vector which make the allocator as the class member:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> 
class vector {
  T* begin_;
  [[no_unique_address]] Allocator alloc_;
public:
  vector() = default;
  vector(const vector& other)
    : begin_(other.begin_), 
      alloc_(std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.alloc_)) 
  { }
};
```

But when I call the copy constructor:

```
vector<int> v;
vector v2(v);
```

**GCC occurs the internal compile error:**

```
<source>: In copy constructor 'vector<T, Allocator>::vector(const vector<T, Allocator>&) [with T = int; Allocator = std::allocator<int>]':
<source>:11:99: internal compiler error: in assign_temp, at function.c:984
   11 |       alloc_(std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.alloc_))
      |                                                                                                   ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

**[But the clang and MSVC can both compile correctly](https://godbolt.org/z/5M114G).** So is this a GCC bug?

**Update:** When I using the flag `-O2` for the GCC, the internal compiler error magically disappears.

Comment: an internal compiler error as the name suggests is an error of the compiler not in your code

Comment: @idclev463035818 Not always - it can be triggered by invalid code that isn't handled properly. GCC Bugzilla call this 'ice-on-invalid-code'.

Comment: @Rup yeah sorry for being sloppy. "internal error" does not imply that the code is free of errors. But still the interal error shouldnt leak out to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is this a GCC bug?

Possibly.

`internal compiler error` doesn't imply a bug in the compiled code. Whether the code is correct or not, ICE can be a compiler bug, or it can be a broken installation.